# Unity stuck inside an object that appear suddenly by SetActive

Tags: unity-game-engine

I set the concept of my game to see the two different world and you can go either world by pressing key code.Tab. So when seeing world1, world2 are invisible and can't affect the player. but the problem is when swapping on to other world if player are inside an wall or an object player get stuck inside of it so I want the player to be pushed out of the object that got stuck to it. I tried googling up for an answer but preventing getting stuck from objects that regenerate randomly but that wasn't my case.

It will be pleasure if anyone can give even an idea on how to solve the problem.

Here is the video resource might help you understand my problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGz-4gUD-bw
sorry for the bad resolution.

Comment: you sure thats the right video? it doesnt seem to match your description at all

Comment: hmm.. on what point do you mean by that? isn't video showing the problem of getting stuck inside of an object that suddenly got set 'SetActive(true)'

Comment: the video shows a platform game and some guy running and jumping at a block - it does not show "worlds" or seem to demonstrte swapping between "worlds"

Comment: for now it is just a prototype of the game and will improve visual effect and others . sorry for the weak explanation. what I'm saying is that if I press 'tab', map placement will change. but on clicking tab key to switch the map. if the player is inside of some certain object, player  get stuck. I want the player to get out of an object and tried solving with ontrigger2d but having a hard time with it.

Comment: I know asking for the whole code is a pressure and won't even help me to improve. so it will be very grateful if you could give me an idea on how to execute

Comment: @BugFinder I think that OP's talking about the blocks in the video (there are four blocks, only two of which are active at a time). At 0:10, you can clearly see the player character getting stuck in a newly-activated block, only leaving that block at 0:12. That block gets deactivated at 0:13. The issue is re-demonstrated at 0:15 (getting stuck in the newly-reactivated block *again*)